# How to remove resource linked to Dialogflow when you dont control the Dialogflow account

Tags: dialogflow-es

`You cannot delete this project in Google cloud platform because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent` but until today I'd never even heard of Dialogflow so I suspect I've been hacked? I tried the link in the error message - nothing.

Comment: I have just edited your question to remove the image you shared because it contains private identifiable information, namely, your project ID. I suggest you remove it sooner if you can. Remember to avoid sharing PII publicly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [common issue](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?hl=cs&skip_cache=true&agent=es&category=project#project-lien):

To learn more about the lien, first check it out in the cloud console:

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list
```

Then follow the instructions to remove it, which will likely look like this:

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. what is cloud console?

Comment: Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard then click the ">_" icon that is near the "?' near the top right corner.  That opens the Cloud Shell where you can run commands like those in my answer.

Comment: got it. but (sorry) next question - i tried the command 'gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list' but i get nothing - how do you find the [LIEN_NAME]?

Comment: The first command lists them, then you copy the name from one and paste it in in place of [LIEN_NAME].